# snapshotID parameter type mismatch when calling Render method on ReportExecution2005.asmx SSRS service

Tags: sql-server, web-services, reporting-services

I am trying to render reports as PDF using the ReportExecution2005.asmx service endpoint on a SSRS 2012 server with MSSQL 2012 backend. When I call the Render method on the web service, I get the following error:
The parameter value provided for 'snapshotID' does not match the parameter type. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ParameterTypeMismatchException: The parameter value provided for 'snapshotID' does not match the parameter type. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

This error occurs with any report I try to render, snapshotID is not a parameter on the reports, and checking the configuration of the reports, they are not set up to be cached or use snapshots.  We just recently moved from MSSQL 2005 to 2012, using the ReportExecution2005 endpoint with SSRS and SQL 2005 I never saw this error, it worked fine.  I've tried adding snapshotID as a parameter with different values such as empty string, current time, etc. but that's apparently not what it's looking for.  Below is the code I'm using to set up and call the Render method on the service.  pstrExportFormat in my case will be "PDF"

```
   Public Function ExportReport(pstrReportPath As String, plstParams As List(Of ReportParameter), pstrExportFormat As String) As Byte()
  Dim lResults() As Byte = Nothing
  Dim lstrSessionId As String
  Dim execInfo As New reporting.ExecutionInfo
  Dim execHeader As New reporting.ExecutionHeader
  Dim lstrHistoryId As String = String.Empty

  Try
     Dim rs As New reporting.ReportExecutionService
     Dim deviceInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo><PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight><PageWidth>11in</PageWidth><MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight><MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop><MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>"
     rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
     Dim params As New List(Of reporting.ParameterValue)
     Dim param As reporting.ParameterValue
     rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

     For Each lInputParam In plstParams
        param = New reporting.ParameterValue
        param.Name = lInputParam.Name
        param.Value = lInputParam.Value
        params.Add(param)
     Next

     rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader
     execInfo = rs.LoadReport(pstrReportPath, lstrHistoryId)
     rs.SetExecutionParameters(params.ToArray, "en-us")

     lResults = rs.Render(pstrExportFormat, deviceInfo, "", "", "", Nothing, Nothing)
  Catch ex As Exception
     Throw
  End Try
  Return lResults
```

End Function

Some additional information, this code is from an app built in VS 2012 Pro and targets the .NET 2.0 framework.  I have tried targeting a newer framework but that gives me a different ReportExecutionService object altogether and I can't assign credentials in the same way, the Render method is also different in that case.

Any ideas on a workaround, or a better way to render reports programmatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this exact same problem today and figured out that, in the LoadReport method, you want to make sure the HistoryID has a value of Nothing (null in C#).  Right now, you're passing it in with an empty string - change the declaration to

```
  Dim lstrHistoryId As String = Nothing
```

Or change your method call to

```
rs.LoadReport(pstrReportPath, Nothing)
```

Comment: Perfect! That was the problem, all is well now after replacing the empty string with Nothing.  Thank you!

Comment: worked like a charm for me when i gave  string histroyId = null; in C#

Comment: XOR, if you happen to be directly making the SOAP call, do NOT specify the Xml element for "HistoryID". <HistoryID /> is processed the same as if you passed in an empty-string.